# Trying to boot Kali Linux from Flash Drive on a Windows 8, just boots Windows 8 instead

Tags: windows-8, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive, kali-linux

It took a lot of headache to get to the point where I actually had Kali installed to my PNY flash drive (using Universal USB Installer), but when I finally reached the moment of truth and tried to manually boot it... nothing. Not even an error message. It just loaded Windows 8 back up as if nothing had happened and there wasn't a flash drive plugged in. I turned off boot secure and put usb as the boot priority, and it blinks a few times on startup, but nothing more than that. Beyond that... I just have no idea. When it came to Windows XP and even Windows 7, this was all so much simpler. Frustration lvl 9000

Is anyone else having this issue? Has anyone else resolved it? Was it something I did wrong?

Comment: Boot to Windows and go to the startup options. Get it to reboot to advanced startup (UEFI) and you'll need to turn off secure boot. You can then get it to boot to your USB.

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with Windows or the version thereof.  Windows can't possibly be responsible for which drive is selected by the hardware/firmware during the boot process.  This is a BIOS/UEFI configuration or hardware issue.

Comment: My computer came with several hardware issues... screen flickers and dies sometimes, bluetooth never worked from the start. So I guess that wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: I had to load it up on vmware instead

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting the one time boot menu to come up (I think that's what they call it in windows). Then select your flash drive from the menu. You pull up the menu by holding down either F12, F2, F9, Esc (escape) or even the delete button on some systems. It all depends on the manufacturer. Make sure that both your flash drive and your hardware are the same (e.g. EFI, UEFI, BIOS) because if they're not the same, it won't work. I'll give an example:

(IRL people I really did this)

I made an EFI Kali Linux bootable drive and my Dell was not EFI so had to make an EFI flash drive to work with my system. If BIOS, then BIOS, if UEFI, then UEFI. Its that simple.